# What's the best way for complex shape matching

Tags: c++, algorithm, image-processing

I need to know what's the best way to match certain shape (template) in the image.

I know there is several ways, but some of them did not lead to a very good results and the another need a lot of process time, so anyone tried a good and fast way to do the matching with short process time.

For example this is the template...

[image]

And I have a sample and I want to compare the sample with the template and return true if the sample is similar to the template else return false.

Note: I tried  contour matching, Cascade Classification, and SURF, but all of them is not very good or the process time is not so good.

Comment: Can you provide some examples of images that you would consider as matching this template? For example, ere you trying to identify pictures of the same type of flower from the same angle, or from different angles? I don't think you'll get a good answer to this question unless you can explain **as clearly as possible** what exactly you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I use feature point cloud comparison + histogram comparison + DCT comparison. But if you want a really robust shape matching then only vectorization is the way. (most of now-days classificators are neural network based which means you need to learn your app to see which is not exact ... it works safely only on a subset of shapes dependend on the learning set)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Matching things with eachother can be a rather difficult task, mainly due to the fact that different techniques have very different characteristics and can yield almost perfect results on some categories and very bad results on others.

This said, I don't think you'll ever get an answer to your question, at least not one that says "Use xyx method from [cited paper], that will solve all your problems". I'll try to point out some examples for you hoping that it'll help.

**Template matching operator**: compare a template with a sliding window on your image, can achieve very good results if your template is **very** similar to the object you are looking for in the image, no matter how complex it is. Can be very fast, it's not invariant to basically anything, so if you plan to have rotations, significant changes in lighting or something else, this is probably not going to work for you. [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html) you can find out some code. Watch out which color space are you using, different color spaces can achieve very different results if used right (e.g. for face analysis HSV can be better that RGB in some cases)

**Keypoint matching** like SIFT or SURF: I used this a lot with very good results. You'll need to decide *what descriptor* to use and *what matcher*. OpenCV has some nice examples,[here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_flann_matcher/feature_flann_matcher.html) you can find one. Not going to be the fastest way to match your object since these descriptors can take some time to be extracted, it's good if you don't know much about the conditions you'll be working in though: it's usually robust to scale, rotation and lightning changes as long that keypoints can be correctly found on both the template and the image.

**Shape matching**: I was rather surprised when, in an image classification competition i participated in, I had been able to use a simple HOG descriptor to obtain very discriminating information about my images. Histograms of Oriented Gradients are a rather powerful tool for describing the shape of an object, it uses edge orientation and magnitude to describe your image. They can be fast to compute (OpenCV has a a GPU implementation I think), configurable (you can decide how thick your grid can be and how many cells, resulting in very different information). HOGs are *not* invariant to rotation, seen the object from a different angle will likely produce a different histogram, but they are very robust to lighting changes due to the fact that doesn't use color. 
HOGs are just an example, there are a lot of shape and contour descriptors but basically they offer pretty much the same I think.

**Histogram matching**: not my first choice, it can be useful if you know something about the object and the rest of image. For example, if you know you are looking for your pink flower in a jungle image where it's the only pink thing there, a simple color histogram matching will do just fine. Pick up a sliding window, run it over your image, compare your histograms and you'll be done. Very fast, very simple, it doesn't use the shape at all so no matter how complex your object is, you'll find it. Not using shape makes it robust to rotations, watch out for lighting changes though. A very big limitations of this method is that if there are other pink things in your jungle you won't be able to distinguish.

**Hybrid approaches**: here is where you can get the best out of the techniques cited above. As you have seen, most of them work well in a certain environment and quite bad in others. You can use a combination of the techniques you know and obtain something much better than the sum of the parts. I worked a lot with HOGs and head pose estimation and a real breakthrough came when we started extracting HOGs not in a dense way but around certain keypoints. You'll need to know your problem, find out what do you need and adapt a bunch of methods to it. In general, hybrid methods can work a lot better and a lot slower.

Hope this helps you a bit, I don't think that, given the information you gave us, I could give you a much better answer..(probably someone else can, that's why I'm still a student :) )